What is the symbolism of "eyes" in the Bible?
Revelation employs the term 'eyes' figuratively numerous times.
Revelation 4:8

And the four beasts had each of them six wings about him; and they were full of eyes within: and they rest not day and night, saying, Holy, holy, holy, Lord God Almighty, which was, and is, and is to come.

Revelation 5:6

And I beheld, and, lo, in the midst of the throne and of the four beasts, and in the midst of the elders, stood a Lamb as it had been slain, having seven horns and seven eyes, which are the seven Spirits of God sent forth into all the earth.

What is the symbolism?

Let me address this question is several stages:
General
BDAG answers the question in a general way by providing two meanings for the Greek noun, ὀφθαλμός (ophthalmos)

eye as an organ of sense perception [ie, literally, an eye], eg, Matt 5:29, 6:22, 7:3, Mark 9:47, Luke 6:41, 11:34, John 9:6, etc.

mental and spiritual understanding, [ie, metaphorical], eg, Mark 8:18, Matt 13:15b, 16, John 12:40b, Acts 28:27b, Rom 11:8, etc.


Now, to the more specific question about the symbolism of "eye" in the book of Revelation.  The ten instances of the noun ὀφθαλμός (ophthalmos) fall into several categories:
Literal Human Eyes

Rev 1:7 - Behold, He is coming with the clouds, and every eye will see Him—even those who pierced Him. And all the tribes of the earth will mourn because of Him. So shall it be! Amen.
Rev 7:17 - For the Lamb in the center of the throne will be their shepherd. ‘He will lead them to springs of living water,’ and ‘God will wipe away every tear from their eyes.’ ” [ie, there will be no more sorrow, a direct reference to Isa 35:10, 51:11]
Rev 21:4 - For the Lamb in the center of the throne will be their shepherd. ‘He will lead them to springs of living water,’ and ‘God will wipe away every tear from their eyes.’ ” [ie, there will be no more sorrow, a direct reference to Isa 35:10, 51:11]

Metaphoric Spiritual Human Understanding

Rev 3:18 - I counsel you to buy from Me gold refined by fire so that you may become rich, white garments so that you may be clothed and your shameful nakedness not exposed, and salve to anoint your eyes so that you may see. [This appears to be an allusion to Jesus' miracle recorded in John 9, especially the final conversation with pharisees in V40, 41.]

Jesus'/Lamb's Seven Eyes

Rev 5:6 - Then I saw a Lamb who appeared to have been slain, standing in the center of the throne, encircled by the four living creatures and the elders. The Lamb had seven horns and seven eyes, which represent the seven Spirits of God sent out into all the earth.

This is a direct reference to the seven eyes of the LORD is Zechariah

Zech 4:10 - For who has despised the day of small things? But these seven eyes of the LORD, which scan the whole earth, will rejoice when they see the plumb line in the hand of Zerubbabel.”

Jesus' Eyes Like Blazing Fire

Rev 1:14 - The hair of His head was white like wool, as white as snow, and His eyes were like a blazing fire.
Rev 2:18 - To the angel of the church in Thyatira write: These are the words of the Son of God, whose eyes are like a blazing fire and whose feet are like polished bronze.
Rev 19:12 - He has eyes like blazing fire, and many royal crowns on His head. He has a name written on Him that only He Himself knows.

All of these appear to be direct references to the blazing eyes described in the book of Daniel:

Dan 10:6 - His body was like beryl, his face like the brilliance of lightning, his eyes like flaming torches, his arms and legs like the gleam of polished bronze, and his voice like the sound of a multitude.

Four Living Creatures' Eyes

Rev 6:6 - And before the throne was something like a sea of glass, as clear as crystal. In the center, around the throne, were four living creatures, covered with eyes in front and back.
Rev 4:8 - And each of the four living creatures had six wings and was covered with eyes all around and within. Day and night they never stop saying: ...

This appears to allude to a very similar vision of the living creatures/cherubim in Eze 1.

Great answer! Regarding Revelation 4:8, one should ask what the purpose of the eyes serve in context. Let me suggest that these creatures are given the task of observing everything that God goes and making judgments as a result. Thus, the expressions of "holy, holy, holy" are not simply adulation, but express continuous judgment of God's actions!

@Dieter - that is very probably true but I stuck to the text alone.

Fair enough. But what can we infer from beings "covered with eyes all around" in context with what they keep saying, day and night? ;-)

@Dieter - the "day and night" is an idiom for "always and continuously without a break" and is a reference to how often they say "holy, holy, holy",  The "eyes all around" is much debated with a variety of interpretations.  I assume that because these being/creatures serve in the very presence of God and are enlivened by God's Spirit that they see all things and inform God.  But that is a guess as are most other interpretations.

Yep, yep, and yep. Does God need to be informed? Perhaps these beings serve God by informing everyone else. ;-)

@Dieter - that is another matter - just let us say that God likes to receive our praise and adoration.

Would you say that our praise and adoration of God is for God's benefit or for our benefit? Just something to think about. It's also why, when I pray "hallowed be thy name," I think of the brilliant design and beauty in the universe, DNA, and the astonishing complexity of our metabolism and the immune system! :-)

Our praise clearly benefits both us and God.

Interpretation of Revelation symbolism is necessarily subjective. The interpreter can offer rationale, but not proof.
My own interpretation rests on the assumption that "seven" is not so much a literal number as a symbol carrying the meaning "belonging to God" or at least "relating to God". Looking at ch1 v4, we see a reference to "the seven spirits who are before his throne". I would take "seven spirits" as "the seven-fold spirit". That is, the spirit belonging to God. That is, the Holy Spirit. On that basis, vv4-5 can be understood as referring to all three members of the Trinity.
Since ch5 v6 explicitly identifies the seven eyes with the seven spirits, I would interpret this reference in the same way. The Lamb is depicted as endowed with the power of God (the seven horns) and also the Spirit of God (the seven eyes). The close relationship between Christ and the Holy Spirit is declared more explicitly in places like John ch16 v7 ("I will send the Comforter") and Romans ch8 v9 ("the Spirit of Christ").
The interpretation of ch4 v8 has to be more indirect, because it is in the first instance part of that chapter's echoing of the description of the four living creatures in Ezekiel ch1. It echoes the statement about the wheeels, "their rims were full of eyes round about" (Ezekiel ch1 v18). But Ezekiel also says that his living creatures moved "wherever the spirit would go" (v12), and perhaps the reference to eyes in both Ezekiel ch1 and Revelation ch4 is a symbolic way of making the same point.
So I offer the working premise that "eyes" are a symbol of the presence and work of the Holy Spirit.
